# Add spaces around semi-colon, unless it’s part of an HTML entity

Tags: php, regex

I want to `preg_replace` all `;` that are not part of HTML entity to add space before if there isn't one yet, and space after (if there isn't one yet).

Eg. : here, select `;` marked `<` to add space before, `;` marked `>` to add space after, and `;` marked `=` to add space around. (Marked `x` have to be ignored.)

```
Hello; Hello ;Hello ; Hello;Hello &egrave;Hello &egrave; Hello &egrave;;Hello&egrave; Hello &#45;Hello &#45;; Hello&#45; Hello
     <       >      x      =             x             x              x=            x           x          x<          x
```

So it became

```
Hello ; Hello ; Hello ; Hello ; Hello &egrave;Hello &egrave; Hello &egrave; ; Hello&egrave; Hello &#45;Hello &#45; ; Hello&#45; Hello
```

Tried to achieve this using this (cf. comments) : [Insert space after semi-colon, unless it's part of an HTML entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10018897/insert-space-after-semi-colon-unless-its-part-of-an-html-entity) but does not work the same way.

Test: https://regex101.com/r/xV4zA2/1

Thanks!

Comment: Why not using `html_entity_decode` before and re-encode the string after if needed?

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte This can be a really long text that I want to alter the less possible… but it's an interesting approach.

Comment: Downvote without explanation comment… ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*[Changed slightly to account for certain edge cases]*

Unless there are some mysterious edge cases that aren't addressed, I think [this should do it](https://regex101.com/r/vM7hX3/1):

```
preg_replace("/(\G|\b(?<!&|&#)\w+|[\W_]) ?; ?/", "$1 ; ", $input_lines);
```

it transforms

```
Hello; Hello ;Hello ; Hello;Hello &egrave;Hello &egrave; Hello &egrave;;Hello&egrave; Hello &#45;Hello &#45;; Hello&#45; Hello
```

into

```
Hello ; Hello ; Hello ; Hello ; Hello &egrave;Hello &egrave; Hello &egrave; ; Hello&egrave; Hello &#45;Hello &#45; ; Hello&#45; Hello
```

*...and now handles certain edge cases as well...*

Broken down, the regex goes like this:

```
(               # begin capture group #1 and match:
    \G          #     [assert at beginning of match]
|               # OR match:
    \b          #     [assert a word boundary]
    (?<!        #     look behind (the word boundary) and assert that there is not:
        &|&#    #         an ampersand or an ampersand and a pound sign
    )           #     end look-behind assertion
    \w+         #     one or more of any word character ([0-9a-zA-Z_])
|               # OR match:
    [\W_]       #     a non-word character or underscore
)               # end capture group #1
 ?              # optional single space
;               # semicolon
 ?              # optional single space character
```

This is then replaced with whatever was in capture group #1 (`$1`), a single space, a semicolon, and a single space:

```
$1 ;
```

Comment: Thanks for regex details!

Comment: No problem - one key to this working is that it captures the whitespace if it's there, and replaces it with whitespace - so if it's not there, it will put it there, but if it is, it will capture and replace it.

Comment: If you encounter an unhandled situation, edit the question with the failing case and I'll re-assess

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte - I would call that an edge case, but I believe I resolved it: https://regex101.com/r/zJ2vH4/2 (this will put two spaces between two adjacent matched semicolons (that are not part of entities), which will be reduced if rendered as HTML, of course ---- this would of course be an argument for the simplicity of doing a replace on the rendered/expanded text as you suggested, but which was not asked

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte -- or [this link](https://regex101.com/r/zJ2vH4/3) for cleaned up version, complete with your additional "as a first character" test case re-introduced

Comment: thank you @joan for the comma to semicolon correction - I think it was rejected due to approvers not looking at the whole context of the question and answer. It was a valid change, and I can change it without community approval :-)

Comment: @CodeJockey didn't figured out that submiting an idea needed a community approval and not an author-only approval… ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think this what you are looking for

Check out this pattern `(?<=o|\s|;);`.

See demo here https://regex101.com/r/uJ0vD4/13

Comment: I believe the `Hello`s were simply example text and could in practice/implementation be any word or series of numbers or punctuation "that are not part of an HTML entity" (?)